# sql query working fine on local but not working on live

Tags: php, mysql

I have written a function of insert and call on button click , Its working fine on local but, when i do same on the live server the function not working. What I missing I didn't get what is the issue . Please help for the same.
Below is the function:

```
function add_query($field,$table){

        //Check if column exist in your table
        $selected_field=array();
        foreach ($field as $key => $value) {
            $result = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM ".$table." LIKE '".$key."'");
            $exists = (mysql_num_rows($result))?1:0;
            if($exists==1) {
            $selected_field[$key]=addslashes($value);
            }
        }

        $key_value = implode(",", array_keys($selected_field));
        $org_value = "'" . implode("','", array_values($selected_field)) . "'" ;            

        $sql="insert into $table($key_value) values ($org_value)";
        $query=mysql_query($sql); 
        return mysql_insert_id();
    }
```

Below is the function call:

```
$insevent=$sql->add_query($field,$table);
```

Comment: which OS version you have in local and which on live server ? .. and also show a sample of $table content

Comment: Not working means Are you getting error or not getting as your expected output or something else. explain it what not working.

Comment: @Sadikhasan it shows the blank on live server

Comment: You have to debug your code at which line of code it quit?

Comment: @Sadikhasan this line not execute $insevent=$sql->add_query($field,$table);

Comment: but this all working fine on local server

Comment: **$sql** variable coming from where can you tell me or show me your code ?

Comment: $sql= new mysql();

Comment: @Sadikhasan mysql is the class

Comment: You should stop using the `mysql` extension. It has been deprecated for many years, and has been removed completely in PHP 7. You should convert to `mysqli` or `PDO`.

Comment: but this also working on other live file

Comment: You should add error checking. `mysql_query(...) or die(mysql_error())`.

Answer (score 0):

Strict mode is enabled on your server
try this

```
set global sql_mode=''
```

i think it will resolve this issue.

Comment: where i put this?

Comment: Why do you think this is necessary?

Comment: @AvinashGupta, just run this query in phpmyadmin on localhost